# How to make my ubuntu auto-shutdown after successful update?

Tags: updates, shutdown, auto-completion

Using a EDGE for update is really not cool but i have to. So my update always runs in night when i go to sleep.

Is there any way to set ubuntu to auto-shutdown after completion of update.

Note: I saw a link in a [similar post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15526/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-after-a-task-has-been-completed) that redirects to a `python` script([SEE HERE](http://kotbcorp.blogspot.com/2009/06/shutdown-after-update-in-ubuntu.html)) but i am not well acquainted with these kind of scripts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The python script you refer to seems fairly harmless.

Comment: Also check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15526/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-after-a-task-has-been-completed/15536#15536

Comment: `ALL=NOPASSWD` is not going well with me :D

Comment: also it's not really recommended...there's a reason you need your password for some tasks ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technically you could do everything in the shell.

Just type

```
sudo -i
apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && shutdown -P now
```

`sudo -i` makes you root till you manually log out of it by using `exit` this is just to make sure that your sudo rights don't time-out if the update takes too long (usually sudo rights time out after 15 minutes if I remember correctly).
The `&&` operator concatenates the commands. Basically you can read it as:
`If command 1 finished succesfully execute command 2, if command 2 finished succesfully execute command 3`
and so on...Note: The other commands will only run if the command before it finished succesfully.

The `-y` parameter after `apt-get` answers all prompted questions with 'yes'.
The `shutdown -P now` shuts your computer down for power-off(`-P`) immediately (`now`).
To get an overview what other parameters there are for `shutdown` run `shutdown --help`

Comment: Thanks @Daniel but the weird thing i have seen in updating through `terminal` is it leaves few updates without installing them. And why `dist-upgrade`?

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` sometimes leaves out some upgrades, notably kernel upgrades. `apt-get dist-upgrade` will however upgrade the kernel, and could remove some packages that `upgrade` would usually not. Visit [`man apt-get`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) for more info, or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade) question.

Comment: like Alaa said 'apt-get dist-upgrade' upgrades all the packages that would be held back by 'apt-get update'

Comment: Won't it upgrade to the latest ubuntu release available at time.

Comment: No it will not do that. `update` only updates packages to their new versions. `dist-upgrade` is able to also install new dependencies and uninstall obsolete ones. So `update` will hold back any update that would require to install new dependencies